# how to let hangouts-chat bot talk to another user while greeted by first one?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a chat bot using Apps Script. The bot can greet the user if user sends Direct Message. Suppose two users talk to the bot separately. Now when a user sends a message "help me", I want the bot to asks the other user "can you help?" and then maybe join the second user to first user's chat, or just confirm with the first user with the second user's response, for example, "yes".

I think I am supposed to send a direct message while processing first user's message

```
function onMessage(event) {
  var msg = event.message;
  var input = msg.text;

  var message = name + " said \"" + event.message.text + "\"";
  if (input=="help"){
    // what should I do here, to talk to another user?
    // suppose I have way to find the other user name, or space name

    message += "help is on the way";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in this [link](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script).  I believe you can use the postMessage function but in onMessage function instead in onTrigger().

Basically, include the OAuth library following the instruction from the link, and use console to monitor the log for any bugs.